# How to move an image from bottom to top in android with in specified time period?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have an image on my android activity page. I want that an image move to top from bottom and then it should be disappear and directly current activity call next activity.

Comment: can you more elaborate about this. Image display by canvas or in imageview etc

Comment: Ok. I use imageview for an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
TranslateAnimation tAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -250);
        tAnimation.setDuration(5000);
        tAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        tAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        tAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        tAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startNewAct();
            }
        });

        i.startAnimation(tAnimation);
```

---

```
public void startNewAct() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, But what is "i" for ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a translate animation for your image that moves it upwards and set an animation listener for it, in the part of the listener in charge of animation end you can place an intent that transfers you to the other activity.